# Best way to store form status settings?

Tags: c#, xml, config, store, setting

I'm working on a project, that have multiple settings on a form, (selections, checkboxes, etc..)
How can I save/store settings, to be able load the same settings, at the next startup?

I've heard about the XML way, but I didn't really found any article, describes how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this MSDN page on [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx). This should get you started! Keep in mind that `User` scope settings can be changed at runtime and saved, while `Application` scope settings are read-only.

**Edit:**

Here is a [Code Project page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UserSettings.aspx) detailing the creation and usage of User scoped settings (with pictures).

Hope this helps!!